# How to include external css in Svelte Custom Element?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I'm new to Svelte and I'm trying to create a custom element that relies on `font-awesome` fonts.  However, when I build the component and try to use it -- none of my styling (including the font-awesome css) gets applied.

I really don't want the user of my element to have to include `font-awesome` on their own -- I want it to just be included as part of my custom element.

Just curious what I need to do to get this to work?

Here's what I have:

**App.js**

```html
<svelte:options customElement="my-custom-element"></svelte:options> 

<script>
   export let overrideCss = null;  //Give user of element chance to override css
   ...
</script>

<!-- Css below is applied when running dev server, but doesn't get applied after build -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/app.css">
<link href="./../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
{#if overrideCss}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={overrideCss}/>
{/if}

<div id="my-app-container">
  ...
  <i class="fas fa-thumbs-{approved ? 'up' : 'down'}"></i>
</div>
```

**svelte.config.js**

```js
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default {
  // Consult https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-preprocess
  // for more information about preprocessors
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
  compilerOptions: {
    customElement: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Show how you *compile* the components. (Also doubt that this is App **.js** )

Comment: I have no experience with Svelte. If your applications supports Ecmascript Modules you can import a styleshee using import assertions https://web.dev/articles/css-module-scripts `import sheet from './styles.css' with { type: 'css' };`. Note, `with` has been substituted for `assert` in the proposal.

Answer (score 0):

To include external styles like font-awesome in your Svelte custom element, you need to make sure the styles are loaded properly when someone uses your component.

First, instead of using  tags in your HTML, you can directly import the font-awesome CSS file into your Svelte component. This ensures that the styles are included when your component is used.

Secondly, you need to configure your build settings to handle CSS imports correctly. Since you're using Vite, you'll want to check your vite.config.js or svelte.config.js file to make sure it's set up to handle CSS imports properly.

By making these changes, the font-awesome styles will be bundled with your custom element, so users won't need to separately include font-awesome when they use your component.

Comment: Do you have any examples as to how to do what you're suggesting?  How do I "directly import font-awesome into my Svelte component"?